# Overwrite the read file with the written one once writing is done python

Tags: python

I read data from a file and I write to another file.

As soon as that is finished, I want to update the read file with the data that is written in the write_file

This is what I am trying.
The write back needs to be in the loop as the read file needs to be updated with the new values.

```py
def execute(read_file, write_file):
    with open(read_file, "r") as in_file:
        reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    with open(write_file, "w") as out_file, open(read_file, 'w') as in_file_a:
        for row in reader:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            wi = csv.writer(in_file_a)
            if not row[0] and not row[1]: 
                row[0] = 'param1'
                row[1] = 'param2'
            a = writer.writerow(row)
            wi.writerows(a)
```

What am I missing?

*Update * This is what I understand from the comments,

```py
global myglobal

def overwrite(read_file):
    overight_file = open(read_file, "w")
    overight = csv.writer(overight_file)
    overight.writerows(myglobal)
    overight_file.close()

def execute(read_file, write_file):

    in_file = open(read_file, "r")
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)

    out_file = open(write_file, "w")
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)

    for row in reader:
        if not row[0] and not row[1]: 
            row[0] = 'param1'
            row[1] = 'param2'
        myglobal = writer.writerow(row)
        overwrite(read_file)

    in_file.close() 
    out_file.close()
```

Comment: Overwrite the read file with the written one once writing is done?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: I'd recommend to avoid reusing variables (`in_file` in this case). Also dont keep the `read_file` opened twice at the same time.

Comment: @Scilla: Well then, do that?

Comment: trying. not working atm. need get lunch. feel free to put solution or I'll come with an update.

Comment: updateted the post. I get `ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode` thsis error

Comment: it says it - you cant use `rw` mode, that does not make sense. Dont nest the `open()` into each other. Read first, then use another `open()` below, not nested inside. Write there.

Comment: If I am not nesting it I get `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` Maybe I need to store it temporarelly somewhere

Comment: I have just updated the problem. still don't get it. wait. it doesnt work cause it don't go out of the loop